# Recursion in Python not working

Tags: python, recursion

I am using python to get the main category of a wiki page by constantly picking the first one in the category list. However, when I wrote the python code to do recursion, it kept returning the first argument I parse in even though I try to change it in the method.

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
string_set=[]

def get_first_category(url):
    k=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(k)
    s=soup.find_all('a')
    for i in s:
        string_set.append(i.string)
    for i in range(-len(string_set), 0):
        if string_set[i] == ("Categories"):
            return (string_set[i + 1])



def join_with(k):
    return k.replace(" ","_")


def get_category_page(k):
    p=["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:",k]
    return "".join(p)

def return_link(url):
    return get_category_page(join_with(get_first_category(url)))




file=open("Categories.csv")
categories=csv.reader(file)

categories=zip(*categories)

def find_category(url):
    k=get_first_category(url)
    for i in categories:
        if k in i:
            return [True,i[0]]
    return [False,k]


def main(url):
    if find_category(url)[0]:
        return find_category(url)[1]
    else:
        print(find_category(url)[1])
        return main(return_link(url))

print (main('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:International_charities'))
```

The category csv is shared:
[Categories.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/647hpufvzq0fksk/Categories.csv?dl=0)

Ideally, the main method should keep going to the first category link until it meets something that is in categories.csv, but it just keep going to the link I parsed in.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main(url):
    if find_category(url)[0]:
        return find_category(url)[1]
    else:
        print(find_category(url)[1])
        return main(return_link(url))
```

Here, you call the `find_category` function which is supposed to return the new url, then you print it, and then you call `main` with the original `url` again. You do not change the value of `url` based on the return value of `find_category`. So it keeps repeating itself.

Comment: I am kind of confused here. I tried to add an extra line in else statement where make url=return_link(url) first, then parse in the new url, but still does not help